# Determine stopping condition while processing dead letter messages from Azure Service Bus queues using Azure functions

Tags: azure-functions, message-queue, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm planning on using a **Service Bus triggered Azure function** to process the dead letter messages. While doing so, I'll clone the message and remove any dead letter properties from the cloned message if there's any.
So, this is essentially going to be a new message with new identifiers. After that I'll submit this cloned message to the main queue for processing.

The edge case I'm looking to address here is that, what if my message itself is corrupt in a way that it can be delivered successfully but the processing fails due to some reason. So, the message is delivered for the maximum number of times to the receiver and then moved to DLQ. After that, my DLQ Azure function picks it up, clones the message and submits it back to the main queue. Now, this can keep going **infinitely**.

**Goals:**

1. How do I determine the number of times this message has been moved
   from the DLQ to the main queue? My goal here is to stop the delivery
   to the main queue after a fixed number of times.
2. What is a suitable design to handle such corrupt messages. I'm thinking that once I'm able to identify such corrupt messages, I'll move them to some table storage for manual inspection.

Comment: What if you add a property to the message as soon as you clone it in the DLQ Azure Function? Put some value in it, indicating that is cloned. If you come across it again on cloning, don't put it back on the main queue but store it in Table Storage.

Comment: Thanks @WoutervanVegchel for this! Will try it out.

Comment: If you looking for a out-of-the-box seamless solution then I would highly recommend taking a look at Serverless360 DLQ automation which allows handling the dead-letter messages automatically. It also allows you to do the Repair and Resubmitting feature with message visualization. https://www.serverless360.com/azure-service-bus-monitoring-management